# Laravel AJAX error when posting

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

```
<div class="tweet-modal-wrapper">
    <div class="tweet-modal w-clearfix"><a class="button-3 w-button" data-ix="hide-tweet-modal" href="#">X</a>
        <h1 class="tweet-modal-heading">Compose new Tweet</h1>
        <div class="tweet-modal-form-wrapper w-form">
            <form class="tweet-modal-form w-clearfix" id="tweet-form"  method="POST" action="{{route('tweet')}}" >

                <textarea class="tweet-modal-textarea w-input" id="tweet"  name="tweet" placeholder="What&#39;s happening?" ></textarea>

                {{--<input class="tweet-modal-image-button w-button"  type="file" value="Photo">--}}
                <button class="tweet-button tweet-modal-button w-button" type="submit" id="tweet-button"><span class="tweet-button-icon"></span>Tweet</button>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
        $('#tweet-button').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'/tweet',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data:{
            tweet: $('#tweet').val()
        },
        success:function(){

            $('#tweet').val('');
            $(".success-alert").animate({bottom: '-=500'}).delay(4000).animate({bottom: '+=500'});
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Error");
            $(".error-alert").animate({bottom: '-=500'}).delay(4000).animate({bottom: '+=500'});
}

    });

});
</script>
```

My controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $input['tweet'] = $request['tweet'];

        $input['user_id']=$user->id;

        Tweet::create($input);
    }
```

The route:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function() {

    Route::post('/tweet', 'TweetsController@store')->name('tweet');

    Route::get('/tweet',function(){

        return redirect()->route('home');

    });

});
```

This is what I'm working with. The error from my ajax gets called every time. Spent the last hour and a half trying to figure it out but no success. I added the csrf token header to my ajax. Tried to do it with the {{csrf_field()}} in the form using AJAX and it still dind't work. Tried to submit the form without AJAX and it works.  I am using Laravel 5.2.29. The value of 'tweet' in my AJAX is a textAreaHTMLObject if that matters. I'm logged in so it can't be the middleware. I moved it outside the middleware and it still didn't work.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Also verify if you've added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your view.

Comment: The token was missing. Thank you for the help! Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Token meta tag was missing from the view

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a bit more by including some portion of your source code where `meta` tag was missing?